Does the EDF converge for non-IID data that satisfy LLN and CLT?
For IID data, the empirical distribution function (EDF) is known to converge due to the Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem, which guarantees uniform convergence of the EDF to the true cumulative distribution function (CDF).
If the data are non-IID but still satisfies the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) and the Central Limit Theorem (CLT):

Would the EDF still converge?
If so, under what type of convergence (e.g., in probability, weak convergence)?

Looking for insights or references that generalize EDF convergence to non-IID data satisfying LLN and CLT.

You'd need to be clear about how these data arise from different distributional possibilities, at least with sufficient clarity to work out what it might converge to.  If you're imagining a potentially infinite sampling process that corresponds to that of an ordinary mixture distribution, I believe it would be straightforward, since its equivalent to ordinary (simple) sampling of a single process that has the mixture distribution as the distribution of its population process.

@Glen_b thanks. I am not interested in what it would converge to as long as it converges to something as the number of samples increases. Mainly trying to understand if LLN and CLT are sufficient conditions when data is non-IID.

If we don't specify some things about how the data-generating process works, how are  we to say anything about it at all?

The point about having some information about the process is so you can show convergence, whether you care where it goes or not. The mixture case is a pretty general one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution but anything broader than that framework would need some sort of conditions to get somewhere.

I was looking at https://econ.nsysu.edu.tw/var/file/133/1133/img/Chapter4_AsymptoticTheory.pdf under independent heterogeneously distributed observations under LLN and CLT sections.

Ah. Perhaps I am being dense. I was focused on  the fact that  Glivenko Cantelli will certainly work for a broad class of cases where means don't exist and the mixture argument would work still. If the ecdf is to converge to something you'd be looking at the convergence of averages of indicator functions.

The EDF will converge uniformly to the average of the true CDFs under fairly weak conditions.  The proof is from one of the standard proofs of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem (the bracketing one).
Write $F_i$ for the CDF of the $i$th observation and define $\bar F_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i F_i(t)$ and $F(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bar F_n(t)$ (if it exists.) Write $\mathbb{F}_n$ for the empirical CDF
If $F(t)$ exists then $\mathbb{F}_n(t)$ converges uniformly to it (in probability if you have a weak LLN, a.s. if you have a strong LLN. I'll assume a weak LLN
Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $-\infty=t_1<\cdots<t_K=\infty$ so that
$$\max_k \bar F(t_{k+1})-\bar F(t_k)<\epsilon$$
For any $t$, let $t^*$ be the first $t_k$ with $t\leq t_k$
Then
$$\mathbb{F}_n(t^*)-F(t)\leq \left[\bar F(t^*)-\bar F(t)\right]\leq \epsilon+\max_k |\mathbb{F}_n(t_k)-\bar F(t_k)|$$
By assumption, we have pointwise convergence at each $k$ and thus uniform convergence over the finitely many $k$, so the second term on the right goes to zero (in probability) and
$$\limsup_n\mathbb{F}_n(t^*)-F(t)\leq \epsilon$$
A similar argument shows
$$\liminf_n\mathbb{F}_n(t^*)-F(t)\geq -\epsilon$$
But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and we are done.
You do not get a Donsker-type theorem this way. Uniform Central Limit theorems involve Deep Magic.
